# Why does bash command "set" lists a different number of variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables, set

Using the bash command `set` directly in the terminal lists round about **47 variables**. But using the following python code with the same bash command, only lists 14 variables:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.getoutput("set > tx.txt")
print(output)
```

Using the php `exec` function to execute the same bash command `set` in a php file, only lists **10 variables**:

```
exec("set 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);
```

Using the `set` command in a bash.sh file and redirect the output into a txt file prints **30 variables.**

Does somebody know why are the number of the output numbers of variables is different in each code?
Why does not all the code displays the same number of variables - 47?

Comment: Some variables are probably set in your `.profile`. This script isn't run in the script used by `subprocess.getoutput()`

Comment: How do I get the same number of variables using python like the set command in the bash terminal?

Comment: Why do you need to get the same number? Most variables you set in `.profile` are only for interactive shells.

Comment: Assuming your shell is bash, use `bash -lic set > outfile` -- that forces an interactive login shell that will process. your dotfiles.

Comment: **@Barmer:** I am using a .env file to store an secret API key outside of my public dir. To load the key, I am using python dotenv libary (because I dont have the option to install the php dotenv libary). So the reason why I want to check all the server variables is, I want to check, If there is any other way for an hacker, to get my secret key.